# How do I save log files to another partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, apache-http-server

I have the following :

uname -a :

```
2.6.31-14-generic-pae #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 16 15:22:42 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
```

df -h :

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             9.4G  2.6G  6.4G  29% /
udev                  247M  168K  247M   1% /dev
none                  247M     0  247M   0% /dev/shm
none                  247M   40K  247M   1% /var/run
none                  247M     0  247M   0% /var/lock
none                  247M     0  247M   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda3              40G  5.6G   32G  15% /var/lib/svn
```

/dev/sda1 is where the webserver is and /dev/sda3 is where we host SVN.

/dev/sda1 is only 10 GB as you can see and some times the apache2 log files become so huge that they take up a lot of space and I see file upload errors. Removing access.log actually takes care of the problem.

Ideally, I want /dev/sda3 to be 25GB and /dev/sda1 25GB but the guys who host this VM say it is really difficult to do that and they say data may be lost and stuff.

I would like to save apache logs on /dev/sda3 instead of /dev/sda1 where they are hosted.

How do I go about doing that? Editing a simple apache .conf file might not do the trick, is it? Thank you!

p.s : I am not a sysadmin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the location of the log files in *apache2* in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
 ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"

 <IfModule log_config_module>                    
     CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log" common
 </IfModule>
```

If you feel like too much information is being logged by apache, you can change the log level in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to *warn*, *crit* or *alert* (please see [the apache documentation page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) for more information on loglevel values):

```
 LogLevel warn
```

If that's not enough, you can also modify the `logrotate` config for *apache2* in `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd`. The *logrotate* for *apache2* is usually configured as a daily cron job.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I reference /dev/sda3 to store the log instead of /dev/sda1?

Comment: I don't have /etc/httpd but I see /etc/apach2/httpd.conf which is blank. I see apache2.conf though.

Comment: And, LogLevel is set at warn for now but error.log files are few bytes. Access logs are huge (333MB or so).

Comment: 1. You could specify the location for CustomLog to a path where `/dev/sda3` is mounted such as `/var/lib/svn/apache-logs`. 2. Ah yes, you would have to configure `apache2.conf` in that case. 3. You can specify the maximum file size of the `access_logs` in the `logrotate` config (and the amount of files that you want `logrotate` to circle between).